# Defining a standard

Tags: standardization

How would you go about defining a standard? I am defining a protocol for a sort of thing that does not exist yet and I would like to create an RFC for it, and use a well-known port number provided by IANA. How do I start?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Check out the [RFC Publication Process](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html), which starts out life as an Internet-Draft

> The RFC publication process includes the stages described below.
>
> - [RFC Submission Process](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html#submission)
> - [RFC Editing Process](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html#editing)
> - [Authors' Final Review](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html#auth48)
> - [Publication](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html#pub)
> - [Copyright Notice and Legend](http://www.rfc-editor.org/pubprocess.html#copyright)
>
> ---
>
> All RFCs are first published as [Internet-Drafts](http://www.ietf.org/ietf/1id-guidelines.txt) (I-Ds). **All RFCs have been I-Ds, but not all I-Ds become RFCs**...

Comment: Among other things, for your I-D to become RFC you will need somebody else to implement your I-D in a way that interoperate with your implementation...

Answer (score 8):

Step 1.  Write it.

Step 2.  Implement it.

Step 3.  Prove that it works really, really well.

Step 4.  Contact ITEF and IANA.  They have web sites.  http://datatracker.ietf.org/wg/ for example, lists the working groups.  Find the right one.  Talk to them.

Answer (score 1):

If all you need is the port number you can contact the IANA using the form provided on http://www.iana.org/form/ports-services to request a port being assigned to you.

You probably should do that early to prevent having to change the port later on.

For actually writing an RFC see [Tom Morgan's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/94905/31260).